# [Android][AssertTesting] Don't stop muti-testing if assertEqual is fail

Tags: java, android

I have to test many testCases to my program,

I use `assertEqual(expect,actual)` to test. But `assertEqual` seems to stop the whole program if it fails. And I hope it will not stop even one of my testCases is fail.

Example:

```
 assertEqual(expect,actual); // if "expect" equals to  "actual +1", it will not run the next assertEqual instead of stop here. 
 assertEqual(expect,actual + 1);
```

I had already tried:

```
try { assertEqual(...) }
catch(AssertionError e){...}
```

But EventLog will show all testCases are PASS even one of them is FAIL...

My question is...

**Is it possible to show which test case is FAIL *and* the whole testCases is FAIL or not?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I use android Studio